# Selecting a dataItem in a Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have KendoUI Grid in an MVC4 application, as shown here:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProjectSystem.Web.Models.ProjectModel>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .Editable(editable =>
          {
              if(User.IsInRole(Constants.Admin)) 
              { 
                editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell);
              }
              else
              {
                  editable.Enabled(false);
              }
          })
      .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
      .Navigatable()
      .ToolBar(toolbar =>
          {
              if (User.IsInRole(Constants.Admin))
              {
                  toolbar.Create();
                  toolbar.Save();
              }
          })
          .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
          .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectId);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Address);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Postcode);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Contact);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Files);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Link).ClientTemplate("<a href='#=Link#' target='_blank'>#=Files!=null && Files.length > 0  ? 'Dropbox' : ''  #</a>");
              columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectStatus);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Active).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkboxActive' #= Active ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>");
              columns.Bound(p => p.Unused).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkboxUnused' #= Unused ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>");
              columns.Bound(p => p.IsSMS).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkboxIsSMS' #= IsSMS ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>");
              columns.Bound(p => p.MaterialLink).Title("").ClientTemplate("<a href='/Material/index?projectId=#=ProjectId#'>#=GetText()#</a>");
          })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                                          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProjectId))
                                          .Batch(true)
                                          .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
                                          .Events(events => events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
                                          .Create(create => create.Action("ProjectCreate", "Project"))
                                          .Update(update => update.Action("ProjectUpdate", "Project"))
                                          .Read(read => read.Action("ProjectRead", "Project").Data("ExtraData"))
      )
      )
```

The ProjectStatus column is an Enum, which has a UIHint called StatusColumn; both shwon here:

**The Enum:**

```
public enum ProjectStatus
{
    Open = 1,
    Closed = 2
}
```

**The View Model:**

```
[UIHint("StatusColumn")]
[Display(Name = "Status")]
public ProjectStatus ProjectStatus { get; set; }
```

**The UIHint (Partial View):**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ProjectStatus")
.BindTo(new List<DropDownListItem>
            {
                new DropDownListItem{Text = "", Value = "0"},
                new DropDownListItem{Text = "Open", Value = "1"},
                new DropDownListItem{Text = "Closed", Value = "2"}
            }
    ).Events(e => e.Select("saveProjectStatus")))
```

**The Problem: **

I am actually trying to get the ProjectId value (a column in the above-shown grid), when the **saveProjectStatus** event is fired on the dropdown UI hint shown above.

I managed to get the selected value as below:

```
function saveProjectStatus(e) {
    debugger;
    var grid = e.sender;

    var row = grid.select();
    var currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(this.select());
    var selectedValue = currentDataItem.Text;

     //     var data = grid.dataItem("tr:eq(1)");
    //   var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
    // var uid = currentDataItem.uid; //.Name;

    //  var dataContext = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);

    //      var parentRow = e.wrapper.closest("tr");

    //var uid = $(e)parent().parent().attr('data-uid');
    //var dataContext = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
}
```

But I couldn't do the same for the ProjectId! I have had several attempts (all commented out above) to solve this in the past hour but no success.

I could also be happy with hiding the row in DOM instead of getting the ProjectId, if that is also possible.

Please help if you can.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your grid is set up to be single selectable, You can access values of the selected grid row like this.

```
$('#Grid').click(function () {
    var gview = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
    var ProjectId = selectedItem.ProjectId;       
})
```

edit: is the dropdown in each row? and you want an event to fire on the the dropdown change and grab the Id of the row?

Comment: @C Sharper no the dropdown is in one column only and yes I'd like to either capture the Id of the row or simply hide it from the dom. Thanks.

Comment: That function will give you access to the Selected Row Project Id

Comment: Where do I call it from? @C Sharper

Comment: That's just a scrip function that will happen when you select an item in the Grid. What I do first to correctly make sure that it is registered, i would just say `$('#Grid').click(function () { alert("hello")})`

Comment: @C Sharper Thank you this helped in that I captured the ProjectId like you said on grid.click() event on document.ready.. I put it in a global variable and then accessed from the dropdownlist.Change() event. then off to the ajax post to update..